# Matlab How to Break Y-Axis and Put Infinity at Top

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, annotations, figures

I am trying to break the y-axis of a plot and put Infinity as my top point, but I can't seem to modify the y-axis labels. Ideally, I'd also like to get rid of that curve ~ line that breaks the plot and instead use the double slashes //, but I tried using a bunch of the break axis functions on the matlab file exchange and I couldn't get them to work for me. However, I'd really also like to be able to compare the look of both methods, so I'd like to be able to see how both ways would look.

**I want to replace the "600" in the figure below with the word "Infinity" *on a broken axis.*.**

I'm using the function [breakyaxis.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45760-break-y-axis)

Here is my code:

```
close all;
clc;

figure
% Plot 
 hold on; plot([0 .2 .5 .8 1],[-10 0 50 100 300],'.','MarkerSize',10); %(:,exp_width)); hold on;
plot(.4,150,'+','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','black');
plot(1,600,'+','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','black'); % Set 600 as point where y value should really be infinity

breakyaxis([350 550]); % Break Axis
xlabel('X Axis'); ylabel('Y Axis');
set(gca,'yticklabel',sprintf('%10s',[num2str(-10) num2str(0) num2str(100) 'inf']));
hold off;
```

Here is a picture of my figure at the moment:
[image: plot]

Comment: So you want a "continuous" axes background ; i.e. white all along and only a // on the y axis to show the break?

Comment: That would be okay, my primary desire is to have "infinity" instead of 600 printed at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for the function `breakyaxis` (type `edit breakyaxis` in the Command Window) we see that we can actually call the function with an output argument, named `breakInfo`, which is a structure containing a bunch of information about the 4 axes created in the function.

The axes called `highAxes` is the one containing the `YTickLabel` 600, which you want to replace with 'Infinity'.

Therefore, assign an output when calling `breakyaxis` as follows:

```
breakInfo = breakyaxis([350 550]);
```

And add this line:

```
set(breakInfo.highAxes,'YTicklabel','Infinity')
```

The plot then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How is this any different from using ylabels = get(gca,'ytick');
ylabels = num2cell(num2str(ylabels.'),2);
ylabels([end]) = {'Infinity'};
set(gca,'yticklabel',ylabels); I need this to work with a broken axis.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question then. I'll remove my answer.